# Creating an errors array and display them through express flash

Tags: arrays, node.js, validation, express, mongoose

I am trying to create an array in which I store and join the errors coming from field validation. What I want to be able to do is display the errors to the user so they can fix the fields before updating their user profile.

The code I have right now is as following and what I did find out is console.log where it `message.push(err.messages)`. However, when I try to output the messages through the messages check, it outputs an empty array []

```
const express = require("express"),
  router = express.Router(),
  validator = require('validator'),
  middleware = require("../middleware/index"),
  User = require("../models/user");
...
...
...
router.put('/', (req, res) => {
  var messages = [];
  var updateUser = {
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email
  }

  User.findOneAndUpdate({
    handle: req.user.handle
  }, updateUser, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      messages.push(err.message);
    } else {
      user.save();
    }
  })
  if (messages && messages.length > 0) {
    if (messages.length = 1) {
      var errors = messages.toString()
    } else {
      var errors = messages.join(' and ')
    }
    console.log(errors)
    req.flash('error', errors)
    res.redirect('/profile/edit')
  } else {
    console.log(messages)
    req.flash('success', 'Your profile has been updated!')
    res.redirect('/profile')
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> when I try to output the messages through the messages check, it outputs an empty array []

This happens because of the asynchoronous nature of the `node`. `messages` will be logged even before the `User.findOneAndUpdate(){}` completes.

To flash messages in sequence after the db call, you need to place it within the callback.

Changing it will result in,

```
router.put('/', (req, res) => {

  User.findOneAndUpdate({
    handle: req.user.handle
  }, {
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email
  }, (err, user) => {
    var messages = [];

    if (err) {
      messages.push(err.message);
    } else {
      user.save();
    }

    var errors;

    if (messages && messages.length > 0) {
      if (messages.length = 1) {
        errors = messages.toString()
      } else {
        errors = messages.join(' and ')
      }
      console.log(errors)
      req.flash('error', errors)
      res.redirect('/profile/edit')
    } else {
      console.log(messages)
      req.flash('success', 'Your profile has been updated!')
      res.redirect('/profile')
    }
  })

})
```